# dependencies for Web Tool Platform XML editor plugin

Tags: eclipse-rcp, eclipse-wtp

I'm developing an eclipse RCP for managing xml documents which also includes the functionality  provided by the wtp xml editor. What are the plugins that i need to include under the dependencies in the rcp to have access to that functionality or how can i locate them using eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually the easiest way to find the needed - on depended-upon - plug-ins is via the Launch Configuration dialog. Simply select the plug-in that interests you and press "Add Required"...